# Unable to resize window using Applescript

Tags: applescript, rstudio, window-resize

I edited the following Applescript using Script Editor, trying to resize the window of my RStudio, but it didn't work. RStudio was loaded, but not properly resized. The codes and the error message are attached below. Any ideas? I'm using macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 and RStudio 1.3.1073. Thanks!

```
tell application "RStudio"
    activate
    set the bounds of the first window to {140, 0, 1160, 775}
end tell
```

[image]

Comment: Is RStudio scriptable at all?

Comment: I don't know. How to check? It was activated though following the execution of the script.

Comment: Press ⇧⌘O. Is RStudio in the list? If not, it's not scriptable. Any application responds to `activate`, `quit` and a few other basic commands.

Comment: Yeah, RStudio is on the list.

Comment: Open the AppleScript dictionary by selecting the app in the list. Is there a `window` element with a `bounds` property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to set the *position* and *size* of a *window* in **RStudio**, you will need to use **System Events** and the *value* of the `properties` of `position` and `size` for the *window*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    get properties of window 1 of application process "RStudio"
```

Returns, e.g.:

```
{minimum value:missing value, orientation:missing value, 
position:{140, 25}, class:window, accessibility description:missing value, 
role description:"standard window", focused:true, title:"RStudio", 
size:{1020, 750}, help:missing value, entire contents:{}, 
enabled:missing value, maximum value:missing value, role:"AXWindow", 
value:missing value, subrole:"AXStandardWindow", selected:missing value, 
name:"RStudio", description:"standard window"}
```

As you can see there is no `bounds` *property*, so `position` and `size` will be used, e.g:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "RStudio"
        tell window 1
            set position to {140, 25}
            set size to {1020, 750}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

---

**Notes:**

- The `list` *items* of the `bounds` *property*, e.g., `{140, 0, 1160, 775}` do not equate equally to `{position, size}` and while the first two `list` *items* do equate to the `position` and `140, 0` actually needs to be `140, 25` because in **macOS Big Sur** the default `height` of the  **menu bar** is 24 pixels, thus making `25` the distance from the top or the screen to the top of the *window*.

Using the adjusted *value* of the `bounds` *property* in your OP, `{140, 25, 1160, 775}`, here are what the numbers represent:

- List item 1: {**140**, 25, 1160, 775} -- **140** is the distance in pixels from the left side of the screen to the left side of the window.
- List item 2: {140, **25**, 1160, 775} -- **25** is the distance in pixels from the top of the screen to the top of the window.
- List item 3: {140, 25, **1160**, 775} -- **1160** is the  distance in pixels from the left side of the screen to the right side of the window.
- List item 4: {140, 25, 1160, **775**} -- **775** is the  distance in pixels from the top of the screen to the bottom of the window.

So while  `140, 25` represent the `position`, `1160, 775` is not the `size`. The `size` base on the adjusted `bounds` is `{1020, 750}` and is derived by subtracting the *value* of `item 1` from the *value* of `item 3` and subtracting the *value* of `item 2` from the *value* of `item 4`.